# The new Custom Font Method in android using xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, fonts, custom-font

As android released its O preview, a new feature has been added called **fonts in xml**. Its easy to implement but i have few doubts.

let me first add the best way to do it
 
1.)Right-click the **res folder** and go to **New > Android resource directory**. The New
Resource Directory window appears.
2.)In the Resource type list, select **font**, and then click OK.
3.)**Add your font files in the font folder**.The folder structure below generates R.font.dancing_script, R.font.la_la, and R.font.ba_ba.
4.)**Double-click** a font file to preview the file's fonts in the editor.

Next we must create a font family

1.)Right-click the font folder and go to **New > Font resource file**. The New Resource File window appears.
2.)Enter the **file name, and then click OK**. The new font resource XML opens in the editor.
3.)Enclose each font file, style, and weight attribute in the font tag element. The following XML illustrates adding font-related attributes in the font resource XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/hey_regular" />
    <font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/hey_bababa" />
</font-family>
```

Adding fonts to a TextView:

```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:fontFamily="@font/ba_ba"**/>
```

As from the documentation all the steps are correct.
my question is:
1.)Can this work in android lollipop or marshmallow
2.)Is any support library needed for implementing the features
3.)What type of font extension will this support like **.ttf .otf**

Please give me the best explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)Can this work in android lollipop or marshmallow

Ans : It's work for lower Version also(Based on my research).

2.)Is any support library needed for implementing the features

Ans : No need support Lib only you need to update your sdk(Android O)

3.)What type of font extension will this support like .ttf .otf

Ans: Yes, Its support .ttf, .otf font Files.

For more info you can see below links :

[Android Doc for Font Family Api](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html#retrieving-system-fonts) ,  [Android-O Preview Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63pKwVE4Uog)

Comment: did you manage to get it working under earlier Android versions?

From the tests I performed, I only managed to get it working under Android-O Dev Preview, running on an emulator. Under 6.0 (API 23) and 7.1 (API 25) setting the `android:fontFamily` attribute to a resource id such as `@font/lobster` has no effect.

Comment: i am nt tried but based on Android Developer demo video they told fully supported(for video click above link Android -O Preview Video). i will try and update my answer

Comment: I have tried on Nougat and `android:fontFamily` worked but getResources().getFont() is not supported. How to get the font dynamically without creating Typeface?

Comment: @tasneem interesting, what versions of Android Studio, the Android plugin, Gradle and the Android SDK Build-Tools are you using?

Comment: @ra3o.ra3 It does not look like depending on gradle version or Android studio. Well I am using gradle alpha 5 and cannery 6. The .getFont() method is not supported lower than O.

Comment: @tasneem I managed to get Android O's "Fonts in XML" working under API 14+ when using the support library version 26.0.0-beta2 and AppCompat. However I was hoping I could use it in app widgets, which is unfortunately not possible, because AppCompat views are not supported in app widgets. There is ResourcesCompat.getFont(...) which should work on API 14+. You need to use the support library version 26.0.0-beta1 or later for that. Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta1

Comment: In my case Instead of <TextView> I used <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView> than its working..