# Android studio font resource directory in sdk 26

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I have create font resource directory in Res directory but if i want to create file xml Android studio don't see me **New > Font resource file** As it is written in to the official guide.
https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html[image]

Even if I insert it manually xml file don't accept tag `<font-family>`
[image]

Comment: Make sure your `resource type` was `font`

Comment: yes, it is font resource and name is font

Comment: `Note: As of Android Support Library 26.0-beta1, you must declare both sets of attributes to ensure your fonts load on devices running Android O or lower.`

Comment: add my manually created xml picture

Comment: nothing. Maybe it was so easy:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060134/the-new-custom-font-method-in-android-using-xml

Comment: sorry but this don't help me

Comment: I guess little mistake happen

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 and higher knows about font resources. Older versions (e.g., the now-current 2.3.3) do not.

Comment: I use 2.3.3. Version 3.0 is stable?

Comment: No , It's on version Beta 2, so if you want to use this feature you need to update SDK to canary channel .

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Studio 3.0 or higher also update your gradle, and your targeted sdk version, build tool version, compile sdk version should be 26 or higher.